# Escaping characters in bash

Tags: linux, bash, thunar

- I use thunar as a file manager
- I want to use "custom actions" on certain files (Thunar --> Edit --> Configure Custom Actions...)
- the command I use is: `xfce4-terminal -e "md5sum '%F'" --hold`

This works fine, except when the file path or file name contains a space. It just won't work as intended because the file can then not be found.

I think this is because the spaces in the file path are not automatically escaped

How do I solve this problem?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Try dragging a file from Thunar into your terminal. Many terminal support drag'n'drop like this to get a correctly quoted path automatically.

Comment: I'd like to use the option in the context menu through "custom actions".

Comment: Sorry. I thought your action contained a hard-coded file path. In that case you could have quoted that one path using drag-n-drop instead of learning all the rules for quoting. I did not realize, that `%F` is a placeholder that will be replaced by thunar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Thunar replaces `%F` with (potentially *multiple*) correctly quoted paths. Putting this inside quotes will ruin the already perfect quoting. From https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/custom-actions

> Never quote field codes

You need a way to pass an argument *list* to a command running inside `xfce4-terminal`. Luckily `man xfce4-terminal` lists:

> `-x, --execute` Execute the **remainder** of the command line inside the terminal

Therefore, try

```
xfce4-terminal --hold -x md5sum %F
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily escape a character with by placing a `\` in front of it.

Comment: %F is a variable which may contain spaces; \%F won't work.